# Correct tag for questions about Apple storyboards

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are currently (at least) three different tags related to the concept of a storyboard in Cocoa: [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard), [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) and [uistoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard).

None of these tags is optimal:

- [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard) is shared with a different technology from Silverlight;
- [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) is named after the Xcode IDE while they are actually a system technology;
- [uistoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard) is the name of a specific Cocoa *touch* class (Cocoa equivalent of `UIStoryboard` is `NSStoryboard`).

Currently the most-used tag is [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard), with close to 5,000 questions, and the vast majority of them are related to the Cocoa/Cocoa touch technology — not the Silverlight technology. The tag [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) is barely used, with about 300 questions, which tends to confirm the fact that this is a bad choice of name for the tag.

So there are two problems here:

- three tag names when one is really needed;
- all three existing names have their own problems.

We need to decide on a policy for that.

Comment: It is a contextual tag, lots of storyboards around, not just in Cocoa and Silverlight.  The combination with another tag makes it obvious, like [wpf] [storyboard].

Comment: Hans, your comment addresses the first problem, but there are still two tags that we should do something about. I'm being frustrated by the lack of reaction on this issue.

Comment: It looks to me you are trying to solve a non-existing problem, no alternative needed :)

Comment: You don't think that having three different tags for the same category is problematic?

Comment: Related -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306442/merge-uistoryboard-into-xcode-storyboard

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I suggest:

- keep the [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard) tag for questions about the Cocoa and Cocoa touch storyboard technology, which means:

  - retag the Silverlight storyboard questions with a new [silverlight-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silverlight-storyboard) tag
  - update the description of the [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard) tag to reflect this
- make [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) a synonym of [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storyboard)
- clarify that [uistoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard) is for questions related to the `UIStoryboard` class, not for questions related to storyboards in general (especially not for Interface Builder related questions).

Comment: There is also a StoryBoard in WPF, just look at these - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+storyboard. So I don't think synonym is a good idea.