# Merge [uistoryboard] into [xcode-storyboard]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

These two tags refer to exactly the same thing. In fact, they refer to exactly the same thing.

In all cases you could just use [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) (or more logically, just [apple-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-storyboard)).

It seems pointless to have "sub-tags" for such a subtle difference **just for the 'storyboard' topic**.

Note that everything tagged with "apple-storyboard" would also have tags for [Apple Watch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Watch), [Apple TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV), Apple blah blah blah.

We can't keep constantly adding "sub-tags" for every Apple technology in the case of the 'storyboard' topic.

Note that in all the other many topics relating to Apple, we don't bother with subtags (phone-topic, osx-topic, watch-topic, tv-topic) .. there's just a tag for the topic (perhaps with "apple" or something added, if it's not obvious).

I'm not sure if there's a general policy on "sub tags".

Comment: Well, not quite, there's also [tag:nsstoryboard].

Comment: hmm, good point.  surely xcode-storyboard should be got rid of?  or just get rid of all three and have Apple-storyboard?

Comment: [uistoryboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard) should be kept, and would be used for both [ios] and [tvos] storyboards.

Comment: cheers, I'll put a reply in the Q ...

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275284/correct-tag-for-questions-about-apple-storyboards

Answer (score 2):

Tagging something as an [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) doesn't identify the type of storyboard.  It's really not a useful tag in itself.

In Xcode 7.1 (beta), there are storyboards for iOS, watchOS, tvOS, and OS X.

I wouldn't suggest merging every type of storyboard into a single tag, as the methods and properties for each storyboard class may differ, while the storyboard XML markup surely does differ.

**The [xcode-storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-storyboard) questions should probably be retagged as [uistoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard) or [nsstoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsstoryboard).**

**Update:**

At present, there's a clear distinction/difference between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.  OS X storyboards are in a different framework from iOS, watchOS, and tvOS storyboards.

That's a good reason why the two different storyboard class tags shouldn't be merged.

I think it's fine to have some overlap with tags, and have a question tagged both [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [uistoryboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uistoryboard), but I don't see any need to make more specific tags to distinguish between iOS, tvOS and watchOS storyboards.

Comment: what is your final recommendation? (its unclear)

Comment: @Joe The [xcode-storyboard] questions should probably be retagged as [uistoryboard] or [nsstoryboard].